# Images not loading in application from a local drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have an C# application to display an image.
I have the following code where I want to display from the local drive as follows:

```
img.src = "D:\abc.png";
```

But the above code is not rendering any image. What could be the correct format?

Comment: try img.src = @"D:\abc.png";

Comment: ..Or `"D:\\abc.png"` (note doubled `\\`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented you can try with `@`

```
img.src = @"D:\abc.png";
```

because `\` will consider as starting of a escape sequence. to avoid it `@` will help

Answer (score 4):

You can try to put @ before the string

```
img.src = @"D:\abc.png";
```

When you apply @ before a string then it means that don't apply any interpretations to characters until the next quote character is reached. If you don't then `\` will be treated as an escape sequence and hence will not work as you think. Technically speaking a string like `@"D:\abc.png"` is known as *verbatim string literal*.

Comment: I think that a short clarification would be viable :)

Comment: @Kamo:- Updated that!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to show same image everytime than why not directly give it in html image tag.

```
<img src=@"D:\abc.png" alt="Alternate Text">
```